# Where are the Docker registry login files?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, docker, docker-registry

I am switching Macs and don't remember my Docker registry login.  I could go in and reset it all, but I would rather copy the hashed login files to the new Mac.

Where are the docker registry credentials stored locally on OSX, Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to find the information I needed in ~/.docker/config.json

Copying this file from one OSX install to another let me authenticate with the registry without requesting credentials again.

The file looks as such:

```bash
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.domain.com": {
            "auth": "HASH_HERE",
            "email": "user@domain.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: little correction: `HASH_HERE` is _not_ a hash, but the actual base64-encoded credentials in `username:password` notation. perfect for using with `curl`. not so perfect from a security perspective

Answer (score 1):

If you have stuck with the [native docker registry V2 (publicatin) authentication](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/89bedf1e7fdda9f7e8814e4d53947d8116b7a36f/docs/deploying.md#native-basic-auth), look for a `auth/htpasswd` (or just `htpasswd`) file that was used to `docker run` the registry.

On Windows or Mac, that file would have been created within the VM, possible under `/c/Users/...` or `/Users/...`, as those are the persistent folders mounted by the boot2docker image.

As the [OP spechal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427387/spechal) comments, the login itself is saved in `~/.docker/config.json`.
[This issue](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/884) for instance illustrates it:

```
WARNING: login credentials saved in /var/lib/jenkins/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
pushing docker image 0fd658e25fd8 from 06bdc8f-1508171450 to docker-registry.tld:5043/repo/ingest_preview:06bdc8f-1508171450
The push refers to a repository [docker-registry.tld:5043/repo/ingest_preview] (len: 1)
```

Comment: While this answer is helpful, I needed the local docker authentication information.  I found it in ~/.docker/config.json

Comment: @Spechal Great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.